# DATEDIFF and the modulo operation giving me empty tables as results

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following tables in sql. I only put in a small amount of table data here for ease of reading and excluded columns that are not relevant for this question.

Table Trip:

```
 ID_Company (FK, int not null)
 trip_no (PK, int not null)
```

Table Passengers_in_trip:

```
 trip_no (PK, FK, int not null)
 id_psg (PK, FK, int not null)
 date (PK, Datetime, not null)
```

The information in the tables is as follows (minimal information included for ease of reference);

Table - Trip:

```
Trip No     ID_Company
 1100            4
 1181            1
```

Table - Passengers_in_trip:

```
 Trip No         IS_Psg       Date
  1100             1         2015-04-02
  1181             1         2015-04-15
  1187             8         2015-05-19
  1188             8         2015-04-27
```

Question / Query: 
For each company, find the number of passengers (if any) that have been transported in April 2015 by ten-day periods.

I have tried the following syntax / code

```
SELECT Trip.ID_Comp, COUNT(Pass_in_trip.ID_Psg) AS Total_PassengerNos, 
Pass_in_trip.date
FROM Trip
JOIN Pass_in_trip
ON Trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
WHERE Pass_in_trip.date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
AND DATEDIFF(day, '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30') % 10 = 0   
GROUP BY Pass_in_trip.date, Trip.ID_comp
ORDER BY Pass_in_trip.date ASC;
```

The results I get back are, are only the headings, with no data

```
ID_Company   Total_PassengerNos    Date
```

I decided to take one back, and try just to get select everything from the table Passengers_in_trip, just to try and find my error, so I completed the following syntax

```
 SELECT * FROM Pass_in_trip
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
 AND DATEDIFF(day, '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30') % 10 = 0
```

This gave me the following table with blank results or not data as well

```
 trip_no     ID_psg    Date
```

If anyone can help me and guide me on where I am going wrong, I would really appreciate, as I have already searched for answers to this and I am stuck at this now.

Thanks everyone
Josie

Comment: Just asking. Do you know that `DATEDIFF(day, '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30') % 10` is always 9 and 9 never equals to 0 ?

Comment: The contradiction is detected at compile time and the table isn't even accessed

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri    - no, but now that you point it out to me, it makes sense

Comment: I have now changed the syntax to read    
AND DATEDIFF(day, '2015-04-01', '2015-04-30') % 10 = 9   ..........I get the results, but they are listed by days such as 2015-04-01; 2015-04-02 etc. I thought I would get a result by 1st 10 days; 2nd days; 3rd 10 days etc. I will have to keep trying to work this out.

Comment: @Josie, can you provide some sample data and desired output.? I can't get what do you want to select. What does it mean `transported by 10 day period`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri    Basically the question is asking me to figure out how many people (ID_psg) were on each flight (trip_no), by each company or airline (ID_Comp/ID_Company) in April 2015, during a 10 day period, so from 1st to 10th Apr; 11th to 21st Apr and from 22nd to 30th Apr. So I was hoping to show results by 10 day period, so for my table (Passengers in trip) above the results would be total passengers as 1 for 1st 10 day period, 2 for 2nd 10 day period and 1 for 3rd 10 day period. I hope that explains what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want number of passengers for first 10 day, then for next 10 days... You need to change the grouping:

```
SELECT Trip.ID_Comp, 
       datediff(day, '20150401', Pass_in_trip.date) / 10 as monthPart,    
       COUNT(Pass_in_trip.ID_Psg) AS Total_PassengerNos,
FROM Trip
JOIN Pass_in_trip ON Trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
WHERE Pass_in_trip.date >= '2015-04-01' AND Pass_in_trip.date < '2015-05-01'
GROUP BY datediff(day, '20150401', Pass_in_trip.date) / 10, Trip.ID_comp
```

Comment: @ Giorgi Nakeuri     That is exactly what I am trying to do. I put your code into SQL Server and I got the following error message              Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column "Pass_in_trip.date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Josie, sure, I forgot to remove that ordering.

Comment: It is still giving me a black result. I copied the syntax over from here, straight to my sql server, so it can't be a typo, even though I checked just to be sure.

Comment: @Josie, I changed where clause because you have datetime column that can contain time part. Show some data in trips table. It should work.

Comment: I got the latest edit, which included       WHERE Pass_in_trip.date >= '2015-04-01' AND Pass_in_trip.date < '2015-05-01'        I still get no results in my table though.

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT *
FROM Trip
JOIN Pass_in_trip ON Trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
WHERE Pass_in_trip.date >= '2015-04-01' AND Pass_in_trip.date < '2015-05-01'`

Comment: A table with headings but with no results.   A message came up to avoid extended discussions in comments and to move to chat. I am relatively new to this site, so does that mean we cannot discuss this here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95144/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-josie).

Comment: @Giorgi.....I might have it sorted, I will let you know in a few minutes. In relation to your last code, I now got the table and the results data. Thank you. I will  go back to the other code and review it again